# Save dates from logfiles into a text file using the datetime library

Tags: python, parsing, logfile

I have to save the date of a log file in a text file.

This is my code so far:

```
from datetime import datetime

with open("logs2merge/archive.log", "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    dates = [lines]
    string = ''.join([str(item) for item in dates])
    for line in lines[:1980]:
        try:
            print(datetime.strptime(line[:23], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f"))
        except ValueError:
            pass

with open("logs2merge/dates.txt", "w") as newfile:
    lines = newfile.writelines(string)
```

The output must be the date from the logfile in the .txt file

Comment: What is your question about this?

Comment: Your `dates` object is a list of a list of stings. 

I think you just want a list of strings

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

date_list = []
with open("logs2merge/archive.log", "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    dates = [lines]
    string = ''.join([str(item) for item in dates])
    for line in lines[:1980]:
        try:
            print(datetime.strptime(line[:23], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f"))
            date_list.append(datetime.strptime(line[:23], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f"))
        except ValueError:
            pass

with open("logs2merge/dates.txt", "w") as newfile:
    lines = newfile.writelines("\n".join(date_list))
```